# SQL Server 2008 R2 Cross Database Ownership Chaining Not working?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

I have restored two SQL Server 2005 dbs (DB1 & DB2) to a new box running SQL Server 2008 R2.

All objects are owned by dbo

I have a stored procedure `DB1.dbo.mp_SPTest`. I have given execute permissions to `SQLUser1`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mp_SPTest
AS
SELECT DB2.dbo.mf_UserHasAccess("BasicUser", "bob")
```

`mp_SPTest` calls a scalar function in DB2 `DB2.dbo.mf_UserHasAccess()`, this function checks if the username passed is a member of a SQL Role.....

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[mf_UserHasAccess] (@RoleName varchar(50), @UserName varchar(128))  
RETURNS bit
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Result bit

    SELECT @Result = 1
    WHERE @RoleName IN (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN (usg.uid is null) THEN 'public'
        ELSE usg.name
        END AS RoleName
    FROM    dbo.sysusers usu
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (dbo.sysmembers mem 
         INNER JOIN dbo.sysusers usg 
         ON mem.groupuid = usg.uid)
    ON  usu.uid = mem.memberuid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN master.dbo.syslogins lo 
    ON  usu.sid = lo.sid
    WHERE   
        (usu.islogin = 1 AND usu.isaliased = 0 AND usu.hasdbaccess = 1)
    AND (usg.issqlrole = 1 OR usg.uid is NULL)
    AND usu.name = @UserName)

    IF @Result <> 1
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 0
    END

    RETURN @Result
END
```

When I run this procedure as "SQLUser1" it tells me that bob is not a member of `BasicUser` but when I run it as "sa" it tells me that he IS a member.

As I understand it... because both procedure and function are owned by dbo then that is the context that the function in test2 db would run, therefore it should have access to the same user and login tables.

This worked fine on SQL Server 2005, cant figure it out.

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the old SQL Server 2005 had the [cross db ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188694.aspx) option turned on, while the new SQL Server 2008 R2 instance has the option left at its default value (off).

But your assumption that 'dbo' in DB1 equate to 'dbo' in DB2 is wrong. 'dbo' in DB1 is the login who corresponds to the owner_sid of DB1 in [sys.databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx). 'dbo' in DB2 is, likewise, the login that corrsponds to the onwer_sid in sys.databases for DB2. If the two logins are different (if the owner_sid of the two databases is different) then very likely 'dbo' of DB1 will map to some other user and the ownership chain is broken, even if enabled to cross databases. Running `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[DB..] TO [sa]` would fix this problem (ie. it would force the owner_sid to match).

And finally, what you're doing is fundamentally flawed, as it relies on activating ownership chaining across databases, which is a huge security hole, see [Potential Threats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx). A much [better avenue is to use code signing](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am happy with the security issues, if I had built the database in the firstplace then all tables would be in the same db. They are seperated Functionally, but shouldn't be.

Comment: cross db ownership chaining is already turned on. `ALTER OWNER ON ` syntax didn't work I used `Exec sp_changedbowner sa, false` but I am still having the same problem

Comment: I have also tried adding WITH 'EXECUTE AS 'dbo'' to mp_SPTest. When I do this I get ..... 'The server principal "sa" is not able to access the database "DB2" under the current security context'. Which seems strange as sa is dbo on that database

Comment: I have mamaged to get this working by adding WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo' to the function mf_UserHasAccess. still don't understand why it is not working though

Comment: I have got this aspect of my problem working, however I am still having problems related to the same thing. I have started a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948863/sql-server-2008-r2-user-cant-use-system-procedure) as I think the title is no mis-leading

Answer (score 0):

I solved this identical problem by making the schema the view or procedure is running under the owner of the schemas in the databases it needs to access.

USE [TargetDB]

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[TargetSchema] TO [SourceSchema]

For example 
USE [DB1]

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[mem] TO [dbo]
GO

Would allow a view run as DB2.DBO.view assuming chaining is turned on, to access a table in DB1.mem.table.  Essentially cross db chaining causes it to access the target DB AS the schema the view is under, not the user who owns the database.