# SQL Server 2008 R2 User cant use system procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have restored a 2005 Database to a new 2008 R2 DB Server. I have created a new user called "gatekeeper"

However this user does not have access to the list of stored procedure in the database.

In a reporting application before running the query the report program is running the following procedure...

`exec [Timesheet]..sp_procedures_rowset N'mp_GetTimesheetToPrint',1,N'dbo'`

When run under gatekeeper user this returns no rows. However when run as sa it returns the procedure.

What is the minimum permission I need to give to gatekeeper for this procedure to work properly. It seems to be a problem with all system objects, none of them fail to run or give permission errors, they just return no results or subsets of the results.

Really struggling with this. Thanks in advance

Regards

Phil

Comment: So the `gatekeeper` user has `exec` permissions on `mp_GetTimesheetToPrint`?

Answer (score 1):

I am honestly a bit confused by your description, so please let me know if I am off base here. You can try this below. It will grant execute access to all stored procedures. If you only need gatekeeper to have access to the one stored procedure, then just grant execute on that stored procedure. If the stored procedure is accessing data from other databases, you may need to grant permissions on the tables and such that it is accessing outside of its database.

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_executor', 'gatekeeper'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. A bit further explanation..This is for a crystal report, gatekeeper has execute permissions on mp_GetTimesheetToPrint and it can run it fine, what seems to be happening, when I run a trace, is that crystal before it runs the procedure for the report tries to get the meta information about the sp. It runs 'sp_procedures_rowset' but this procedure returns no rows when run as gatekeper but does when run as sa

Comment: If I give gatekeeper the securityadmin role then it works fine, however I don't really want to do this.